# Populate a 2d array from SimpleXML, then sort by first column

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, simplexml

I have a product xml with multiple sellers that have different prices. I need to sort the array somehow after I loo through the simpleXML object and put it in an array.

Loop through xml file:

```
foreach ($item->Offers->Offer as $offer) {
    $trackerprices[]['price'] = $offer->Price;
    $trackerprices[]['id_seller'] = $offer->Seller->Id;
}
```

So when I `var_dump($trackerprices)` it outputs:

```
array(18) {
    [0]=> array(1) {
        ["price"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#22 (1) {
            [0]=> string(4) "10.0"
        }
    }
    [1]=> array(1) {
        ["id_seller"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#26 (1) {
            [0]=> string(16) "1001004002814931"
        }
    }
    [2]=> array(1) {
        ["price"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#16 (1) {
            [0]=> string(4) "8.29"
        }
    }
    [3]=> array(1) {
        ["id_seller"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#28 (1) {
            [0]=> string(6) "187216"
        }
    }
    [4]=> array(1) {
        ["price"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#24 (1) {
            [0]=> string(3) "9.0"
        }
    }
    [5]=> array(1) {
        ["id_seller"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#30 (1) {
            [0]=> string(6) "441404"
        }
    }
    [6]=> array(1) {
        ["price"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#25 (1) {
            [0]=> string(4) "9.75"
        }
    }
    [7]=> array(1) {
        ["id_seller"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#32 (1) {
            [0]=> string(5) "25430"
        }
    }
    [8]=> array(1) {
        ["price"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#27 (1) {
            [0]=> string(4) "9.95"
        }
    }
    [9]=> array(1) {
        ["id_seller"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#34 (1) {
            [0]=> string(6) "150362"
        }
    }
    [10]=> array(1) {
        ["price"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#29 (1) {
            [0]=> string(3) "8.0"
        }
    }
    [11]=> array(1) {
        ["id_seller"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#36 (1) {
            [0]=> string(6) "502339"
        }
    }
    [12]=> array(1) {
        ["price"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#31 (1) {
            [0]=> string(3) "9.0"
        }
    }
    [13]=> array(1) {
        ["id_seller"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#38 (1) {
            [0]=> string(6) "117478"
        }
    }
    [14]=> array(1) {
        ["price"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#33 (1) {
            [0]=> string(4) "15.0"
        }
    }
    [15]=> array(1) {
        ["id_seller"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#40 (1) {
            [0]=> string(6) "153058"
        }
    }
    [16]=> array(1) {
        ["price"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#35 (1) {
            [0]=> string(3) "6.5"
        }
    }
    [17]=> array(1) {
        ["id_seller"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#42 (1) {
            [0]=> string(6) "402391"
        }
    }
}
```

No I need a way to sort the output by price ASC.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you probably want to use this structure:

```
foreach($item->Offers->Offer as $offer) {
  $trackerprices[] = array('price' => (float)$offer->Price, 
                           'id_seller' => (string)$offer->Seller->Id);
}
```

This way, you keep the price and the corresponding seller_id together. So now you have an array of price-seller-pairs and you need it to sort by the price-field of each pair. You can use [multisort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) for that. This is only one way to do it, there may be more efficient solutions.

```
foreach($trackerprices as $tp) {
     $sort[] = $tp['price'];
}
array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, $trackerprices);
```

All together, it's 3 more lines of code:

```
$sort = array();
foreach($item->Offers->Offer as $offer) {
  $trackerprices[] = array('price' => (float)$offer->Price, 
                           'id_seller' => (string)$offer->Seller->Id);
  $sort[] = $tp['price'];
}
array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, $trackerprices);
```

I haven't tested it, but you get the idea and I hope it helps.